# Background loading javascript into iframe without using jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an offline only help system which requires loading a large amount of search-related data into an iframe before the search functionality can be used.   Due to the folder structure of the project, I am unable to use Ajax-related background load methods, since the files I need are loaded a few directories "up and over."

I have written some code which delays the loading of the help data until the rest of the webpage is loaded.  The help data consists of a bunch of javascript files which have information about the terms, ect that exist in the help books which are installed on the system.

The webpage works fine, until I start to load this help data into a hidden iframe.  While the javascript files are loading, I can not use any of the webpage.  Links that require a small files be downloaded for hover over effects don't show up, javascript (switching tabs on the page) has no effect.

I'm wondering if this is just a limitation of the way javascript works, or if there's something else going on here.   Once all the files are loaded for the help system, the webpage works as expected.

```
function test(){
   var  MGCFrame = eval("parent.parent");
    if((ALLFRAMESLOADED == true)){
        t2 = MGCFrame.setTimeout("this.IHHeader.frames[0].loadData()",1);

}
   else{

  t1 = MGCFrame.setTimeout("this.IHHeader.frames[0].test()",1000);
  }
  }
```

Load data simply starts the data loading process.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading quite a few javascript files--- around 200 or so.  I minimized the delay by combining some files, and using jquery's getScript function for the others.  To help the browser not lock up while loading all these files, I populated a global array with a list of the files which needed to be downloaded, and then recursively called a helper function which waited 100ms, then called getScript, then called itself.  This helped background load the files without making the browser unusable.

Comment: Continuation of this topic here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158102/loading-large-amount-of-data-into-memory-most-efficient-way-to-do-this